# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionType

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am upgrading application to springBootVersion=2.5.2, springCoreVersion=5.3.8. It's throwing exception.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'elasticsearchTemplate' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchDataConfiguration$RestClientConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate]: Factory method 'elasticsearchTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/ActionType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:658) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:638) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1334) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.saif.application.MyApplication.main(MyApplication.java:14) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate]: Factory method 'elasticsearchTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/ActionType
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:653) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate]: Factory method 'elasticsearchTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/ActionType

    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/ActionType
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.initialize(AbstractElasticsearchTemplate.java:103) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
    at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.<init>(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:118) ~[spring-data-elasticsearch-4.2.2.jar:4.2.2]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/ActionType

    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataConfiguration$RestClientConfiguration.elasticsearchTemplate(ElasticsearchDataConfiguration.java:94) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.action.ActionType
```

I have following dependencies

```
    implementation "org.springframework.data:spring-data-elasticsearch:4.2.2"
    implementation "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:6.5.4"
    implementation "org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-client:6.5.4"
    implementation "org.elasticsearch.client:elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client:6.5.4"
```

Elastic Search version is 6.5.4 in production. Is there fix our should i downgrade spring to some other version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last version to use Elasticsearch 6 libraries would be Spring Data Elasticsearch 3.2.x (which is EOL and not supported anymore); this was used by Spring Boot 2.2.

Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.2 is built with Elasticsearch 7.12 libraries and won't work with version 6.

Comment: It seems Spring Boot 2.4.4 is the last version compatible with Elastic Search 6.5.4